# Cannot execute command using exec() in php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, exec

Ive tried searching for the answer but cant find anything proper in relation to my case.

What i want to execute is very simple...its a call to the SPMF framework jar file.

here is the code -

```
<?php

exec('java -jar spmf.jar run Apriori /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/ip.txt /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/output.txt %20');
?>
```

why is this not executing?
it obviously runs perfectly using cli.
the folder having all the files (jar file,ip.txt,output.txt) have permissions set to r/w to all users

I am on Linux - Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Have you activated exec in your php.ini in your environment? (what is your environment? Linux/Windows?)

Comment: Some errors? Have you tried to print exec result?

Comment: @doydoy44 its linux...and i dont think i have done that...please guide me..

Comment: @Fede_Reghe no errors

Comment: @user3405210, before php 5.4 this is [same_mode](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)

Comment: @doydoy44 m using php 5.5

Comment: @user3405210, sorry I can't help you. good luck. :)

Comment: @doydoy44 .. :( okay...np... thanx anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was in the path to the spmf zip file.

Either it needs a full path or should be in the same folder as the script.

I solved it by placing it in the folder same as the script.( under htdocs as i am using lampp)

Also, the folder needs to have permissions for other to be set to "Create and Delete" for php to be able to access and write output to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Basic debugging: If exec() doesn't work, then you need to check return values:

```
exec('some command here', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output, $return_var);
```

NEVER assume that an external resource succeeded. ALWAYS check return values and output for error messages.

Most likely `java` isn't in the path of whatever shell PHP is using to handle the exec() call, meaning you'll need `exec('/full/path/to/java ...')` instead.

Comment: okay here is the op of the command on following ur steps - `array(0) { } int(1)`

Comment: adding the path `/usr/bin/java` isnt working either. :(